# tshark outputting all fields?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tshark

Is it possible to get `tshark` output every field (within the packet) using the `-T fields` option, or similar?

e.g. For every field in the packet/reconstruction, I would like something like this:

```
eth.src:f2:3c:91:96:fd:09,ip.src:1.2.3.4,tcp.dst_port:80,http.request.uri:/index.html
```

(The comma could be replaced with a `\xff` to make parsing better when values contain commas.)

I realise there is the `-e` option but it seems that I would have to put in every single possible field in the command line. On top of that, only a small fraction of fields will be used in each packet, which makes for a lot of data to parse.

I currently plan to use the `tshark -V` option and parse that, but ideally I would like more machine style terms such as `http.request.uri` instead of "human readable" e.g.:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET /main.php HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET /main.php HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Message: GET /main.php HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: GET
        Request URI: /main.php
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just stumbled across:

```
tshark -T pdml
```

which is exactly what I need:

```
<packet>
  <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="173">
    <field name="num" pos="0" show="323" showname="Number" value="143" size="173"/>
    <field name="len" pos="0" show="173" showname="Frame Length" value="ad" size="173"/>
    <field name="caplen" pos="0" show="173" showname="Captured Length" value="ad" size="173"/>
    <field name="timestamp" pos="0" show="Aug  7, 2011 16:16:13.579504000 EST" showname="Captured Time" value="1312697773.579504000" size="173"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="frame" showname="Frame 323: 173 bytes on wire (1384 bits), 173 bytes captured (1384 bits)" size="173" pos="0">
    <field name="frame.time" showname="Arrival Time: Aug  7, 2011 16:16:13.579504000 EST" size="0" pos="0" show="Aug  7, 2011 16:16:13.579504000"/>
    ... etc.
```

It includes the Wireshark filter name, as well as all the fields that are included in the packet.

**Update**: This is quite slow, and hacking up `tshark.c` so `-V` prints out the `abbrev` instead of the `name` in the `header_field_info   *hfinfo;` does the trick too. I should probably contribute this an a option when I get the chance.

Comment: how hack up tshark.c? Can u guild or example for me? Thanks